# How to use a sheet name that is referenced in a cell in a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Column B is a list of my sheet names created using Index. I simply want the formula in column C to go to a certain cell on whatever sheet name is listed in column B. I'm struggling with what I think is very simple? I have a formula that works, but it doesn't allow me to change the name of the sheet. I thought it would be something like `='B4'!$P$33`

[image: My formula thus far.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `INDIRECT` function to return the reference specified by a string.

You just concatenate your string and wrap it with the function.

```
=INDIRECT(B4&"!$P$33")
```

Comment: If I'm combining cells from sheet B4, do I need to use indirect before each cell reference? Currently I have =INDIRECT(B16&"!$B$8&""&$C$8&""&$D$8&""&$E$8)

Answer (score 1):

Say we wanted:

```
=Sheet1!Z100
```

but wanted to put the sheetname in a separate cell.  Use:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & B4 & "'!Z100")
```

Please note the single quotes!

[image]